# Cannot move windows to second screen

Tags: 14.04, gnome, multiple-monitors

I have an external monitor plugged into my notebook, but I cannot move windows from the bottom screen (built-in screen) to the upper screen (external monitor).

The windows stick at the top border (below the panel) of the built-in screen, while the mouse moves into the second screen.

I think, it's because of the top panel; It works if I place the external monitor below the built-in screen.

How can I solve this issue? Or move windows directly without using drag and drop.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Go to Settings->Display.

[image]

Turn Off Sticky edges.

Solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left-click</kbd> anywhere in the window (E.G. the bottom) and then move it...

Answer (score 0):

Either drag the window straight through, passing the place where the window goes full screen, or try every side of the main screen. If not just try to go through each side of the main window with your mouse to get it to show up on the top monitor.

Comment: I think I didn't get what you were trying to say.

Comment: Sorry, let me fix that

Comment: Maybe I should state this more clearly, but thats exactly my problem: I cannot move the window straight through, because it stops moving just below the panel. Because the mouse is already in the second screen, full screen isn't triggered for this window.

Comment: What do you mean by
`Because the mouse is already in the second screen, full screen isn't triggered for this window.`

Comment: And did you try to drag the windows trough the other sides?

Comment: Yes. It works, if the external screen is configured to be below the built-in screen (see question), but not if it's above the primary screen. (Other edges work, if the external screen is configured to be on that side)

Comment: Go to system settings, then click displays, then turn sticky edges off. Try that.

Comment: I can remember I tried that and it didn't work, but currently I can't find that option: http://i.imgur.com/zAIWQZD.png

Comment: huh. Well I use 14.04, so my fault on that one, but for now, just open the windows again in the other screen. I'll be looking into that for a _while_ if ya know what I mean.

Comment: OH! WAIT! Move the screen to the left in the displays menu, then you can drag the window from there. It may just be that 12.04 doesn't allow dragging windows through the top. You can change that in compiz-cofig. give me a bit to tell you what to do.

Comment: In terminal
`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
go to window manager, then unselect snapping windows. Try that if the previous suggestion won't work.

Comment: _Move the screen to the left in the displays menu, then you can drag the window from there:_ I already stated that in my start post. It's no solution, because the screen is above my notebook and any other setting is just weird. _12.04:_ I'm using 14.04 as stated in the question's tags. In `compiz-config` I can change that setting, but still can't drag windows to the second screen, if it's above the built-in.

Comment: Okay. 12.04 just doesn't have the feature of dragging windows through. You'll either have to open them up in the other window or upgrade. sorry D:

Comment: Upgrade? There's no newer version.

Comment: i mean to 14.04

Comment: As already stated: It's a fresh 14.04 installation.

Comment: oops. I thought for some reason u used 12.04. This is in-explainable! Did you try Compiz?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on Ubuntu 14.10. I have a dell Latitude e7440 running with 2 additional screens for a total of 3 screens thanks to this post:

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/358

After having my screens working I was disappointed because I wasn't being able to drag a window e.g. the Mozilla browser, from one screen to the other, but I found that under System Settings -> Screen Display, there is an option called "Sticky edges". If you set that to OFF the dragging of windows though screens will work :)

Comment: The link does no longer work it seem. Is it possible to describe what you did?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me!  (20.0.4) The easiest workaround I could find was making the second monitor the primary monitor.  After that all dragging worked!

Answer (score -1):

I just happen to have the same problem with 16.04 and here is what it fixed it for me.

Go to the "burger menu" on the right end of the control bar. Then select "additional settings" and allow the programs to "slip" under the control bar.

I'm not sure with the exact wording since I'm using the German localization.

Comment: To get around localization differences: you can make most programs print English messages and UI text by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free`. A screenshot of the settings dialogue would help too.